# Why the ‘Char’ identifier could not be recognised in VS2013?

Tags: c++

I am just using VS2013 to build the HEVC reference software. Here, I write a C++ file and want to build it. However, it always shown that 'Identifier "Char" is not defined'.

I also use 'UChar*' and it is ok in VS2013, but the 'Char*' is shown not defined...

I am confused about this. Could you please me with this?

Thanks in advance!

I tried to use 'Char*' to define the string variable in VS2013, however, it returned error message....

```
void recordMBInfo(TComDataCU*& pcCU, SliceType sliceType)
{
Char* modeInfo;
Char* parSize = pcCU->getPartitionSize();
Bool* skipFlag = pcCU->getSkipFlag();
Char* preMode = pcCU->getPredictionMode();
UChar* puhDepth = pcCU->getDepth();

Char* phQP = pcCU->getQP();


modeInfo = new Char[pcCU->getTotalNumPart() + 1];
```

My problem is that the 'UChar*' is correct in VS2013, but 'Char*' returned error message. I am not sure the reason about this.

Comment: And `Char` is exactly defined where? You probably wanted to use `char` instead.

Comment: `Char` is neither a standard type nor a type provided by the Windows API (it provides `CHAR`). It's not clear to why you expect `Char` to be defined or by what.

Comment: C++ has no such types. Both UChar and Char are custom types defined in one header or another. Probably a header with a similar name to the one that defined UChar

Comment: Check [String and Character Literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/string-and-character-literals-cpp?view=vs-2019) in the Visual C++ docs. It explains that the C++ standard character types are `char` for 8-bit characters, `char16_t` for UTF16, `char32_t` for UTF32 and that the STL string types are string, u16string and u32string

Comment: Hi all, the problem has been solved. Both of you are right, I forgot to modify the definitions of 'Char' in a header. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither `Char`, `UChar`, nor `Bool` are defined as types by the C++ standard.

They are most likely part of a library like MFC or ATL, and are probably (you can but hope) `typedef`s for primitive types like `char`, `unsigned char`, and `bool`.

Since neither `TComDataCU` nor `SliceType` are not C++ standard classes either, it's probably a simple case of studying the documentation associated with that class, to see what other headers you need to include.

Comment: Thanks, Bathsheba! I just forgot to modify the definitions of 'Char'

Answer (score 3):

Char is not a primitive type. I think you might refer to char. If you want to use Char, you must define the meaning of Char. Maybe you forgot a library in which Char is defined.

Comment: Thanks, Theodor Badea! The problem has been solved, you are right, I forgot to correct the definitions of 'Char' in a header.